# What is the Haskell idiom for walking a file and filling a structure when only some of the data is interesting?

Tags: haskell

Often I find I need to parse a little bit of text. Usually the text is not lines of uniform data like CSV rather it is more unstructured. So the goal is not to turn each line into a Haskell data type but to gather up data into a structure.

In an imperative language I would write something like this.

```
values = {}  # could just as easily be a class or C struct

for line in input_lines:
    if line matches A:
        parse out interesting piece
        values[A] = parsed chunk
    elif line matches B:
        parse out interesting piece
        values[B] = parsed chunk
    ...
    elif line matches Z:
        parse out interesting piece
        values[Z] = parsed chunk
        break  # we know there is nothing else after this

do something with values
```

I wrote a bit of Haskell this morning to do the same thing using `foldr`.
This parses the output of rsync --stats. A sample file looks like this.

```
Number of files: 1
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 4953701 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 10 bytes
Matched data: 230 bytes
File list size: 43
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 11
Total bytes received: 57

sent 11 bytes  received 57 bytes  12.36 bytes/sec
total size is 4953701  speedup is 72848.54
```

Small and simple to demonstrate my problem. This particular file format is representative of this recurring style of problem where I want to quickly read 3 or 5 bits from a file and doing something else with the results. In an imperative language I'd just toss them into a few variables, a dictionary, something. The Haskell below is my attempt at a similar approach.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import Data.Text.Read (decimal)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

stats_map :: M.Map Text Int
stats_map = foldr (uncurry M.insert) M.empty [("Total file size", 1),
                                              ("Literal data", 2),
                                              ("Matched data", 3)]

getStatsMap :: Text -> M.Map Text Integer -> M.Map Text Integer
getStatsMap t rm = doMatch chunks rm
  where
    chunks = [ T.strip chunk | chunk <- T.splitOn ":" t ]

  doMatch :: [Text] -> M.Map Text Integer -> M.Map Text Integer
  doMatch (f1:f2:_) rm' =
    case M.lookup f1 stats_map of
      (Just _) -> case decimal . head . T.words $ f2 of
                    Left _      -> rm'
                    Right (x,_) -> M.insert f1 x rm'
      Nothing  -> rm'
  doMatch _ rm' = rm'

parseStats :: [Text] -> M.Map Text Integer
parseStats ts = foldr getStatsMap M.empty ts

readStats :: FilePath -> IO [Text]
readStats filename = TIO.readFile filename >>= return . T.lines

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [filename] <- getArgs
  lines <- readStats filename
  putStrLn . show . parseStats $ lines
```

Unlike in the imperative version I cannot break the `foldr` execution though.
Laziness cannot rescue me here. Parsec, attoparsec and friends are both overkill and not exactly what I am looking for this kind of task.

How can I approach this common imperative task in a more Haskell way?

Comment: You could possible sequence something using a failure monad. I'm not exactly sure what your code sample ought to be doing, but Either has short-circuiting behavior—once it sees a `Left` value it just skips computations.

Comment: The problem is ``Either`` drops anything from ``Right`` if a ``Left`` is passed and ``Maybe`` does the same if a ``Nothing`` occurs. This means I can't use ``foldM``. ``unfoldr`` has some of the semantics I want but the intermediate results are bound in a list when I only want the complete computation. I can whip up a ``foldUntil`` and have my ``doMatch`` function return a tuple with a ``Bool`` and the result. But my ``doMatch`` has 3 cases where nothing happens. Surely there is a better way.

Comment: I think it would help if you gave more details about the file format in question. In any case, it looks like you're doing way too much work. I might be able to give it a closer look once I'm done with an exam.

Comment: I don't disagree @kqr. I added some sample for the file format but as I say in the question the file format is not the point. There are numerous random formats that come up day to day. Sometimes it is reading the output of another program, sometimes a small file like this, etc.

Comment: You can easily break out of the `foldr` execution.  Just return a default map in that case instead of `rm'`.

Comment: Won't that discard the previous values in the map I have been building?

Comment: Surely a Haskell idiom for this is not to use `foldr` but to have `grok :: InputType -> Maybe OutputType` and then do `catMaybes . map grok` of type `[InputType] -> [OutputType]`. You can then throw those together in a map as you see fit.

Comment: But @AndrewC, doesn't that assume I am creating a group of similar values? In many cases I am not making a data structure for each line but instead one for an entire file. Using ``catMaybe`` as you suggest would have me making one element ``Map``s that then get added together using my current code.

Comment: You put the parsed chunks in `Just` and return `Nothing` when there's nothing interesting. The list and catMaybes is to replicate the break in the imperative code.It would help enormously if you could give some example output to match some example input.

Comment: Your Just could be `Just (key,interesting)` and then your throw-together is just `fromList`, giving `makeMap = fromList . catMaybes . map grokPair` where `grokPair :: InputType -> Maybe (KeyType,OutputType)`, but like I say, some example output would be handy.

Comment: The point of the break in imperative code is to stop looking at input once a condition is met. A list of input lines transformed into a list of ``Maybe Foo`` to then walk and process is not any better than the current situation. Laziness is not an aid here since a typical result would be ``[Nothing, Nothing, ..., Int, Int, Nothing, Nothing,....]`` so we can't just stop processing when a ``Nothing`` is reached.

Comment: @SeanPerry: my suggestion would not discard the results you've been accumulating, since `foldr` is a right fold.  It would discard every part of the input you haven't yet looked at, which is the behavior you want in this case.

Comment: But laziness _does_ rescue us if you know in advance how many there will be, because `take 3` short-circuits. `take 3.catMaybes` discards any `Nothing`s until it's collected three `Just`s. Map seems overkill if you're just grabbing three things.

Comment: I made this simple so we could all discuss it. Usually the number is more like 7 - 10. ``map`` may still be overkill then but the code is easy to follow. I often write things and leave them for other people so simple is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone for simple data structures to try to emphasise that the behaviour's there in the standard ones if you want it:

First version - using `catMaybes` and `take` to ignore irrelevant data and shortcut:

```
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)
import Data.Char (isDigit)
import Control.Monad (msum)

-- maybe get an int if the key matches before :

get :: String -> String -> Maybe Int
get key input = let (l,r) = break (==':') input in
                if l == key then Just . read . filter isDigit $ r
                            else Nothing

-- get any that match

getAny :: [String] -> String -> Maybe Int
getAny keys input =  msum $ map (flip get input) keys

-- get all that match at least one

getThese :: [String] -> String -> [Int]
getThese keys = take (length keys) . catMaybes . map (getAny keys) . lines
```

This gives you the output you were after:

```
fmap (getThese ["Total file size","Literal data","Matched data"]) (readFile "example.txt")  >>= print
[4953701,10,230]
```

and we can check that it's shortcutting by feeding it a bomb to eat:

```
> getThese ["a"] (unlines ["no","a: 5",undefined])
[5]
```

### Sometimes recursion is simpler

Pick out one element for each predicate in order:

```
oneEach :: [(a->Bool)] -> [a] -> [a]
oneEach [] _ = []
oneEach _ [] = error "oneEach: run out of input while still looking"
oneEach qs@(p:ps) (i:is) | p i   = i : oneEach ps is
                         | otherwise = oneEach qs is
```

Compose some functions to split the string and pull out the ones we wanted, then read the data. This assumes you want all the digits to the right of the `:` as your Int

```
getInOrder :: [String] -> String -> [Int]
getInOrder keys = map (read.filter isDigit.snd)
                 . oneEach (map ((.fst).(==)) keys)
                 . map (break (==':'))
                 . lines
```

which works:

```
main = fmap (getInOrder ["Total file size","Literal data","Matched data"]) (readFile "example.txt")  >>= print
[4953701,10,230]
```

Comment: I had not fully realized just how lazy the lazy IO was. A little tweak to ``get`` so it returns a tuple containing the key that matched and this will match my code's behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This version is primitive in some ways (hard codes some things, doesn't handle ordering), but may be more readable:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.List.Utils
import Data.Char

main = do 
  [filename] <- getArgs
  txt <- readFile filename
  let ls = lines txt
  let ils = filter interestingLine ls
  putStrLn $ show $ map fmt (filter (/="") ils)

interestingLine l = startswith "Literal data" l
          || startswith "Matched data" l
          || startswith "Total file size" l 

fmt :: String -> (String,Int) 
fmt l  | startswith "Literal data" l = (take 14 l,(read $ filter isNumber l))  
       | startswith "Matched data" l = (take 14 l,(read $ filter isNumber l))
       | startswith "Total file size" l = (take 17 l,(read $ filter isNumber l))
       | otherwise = error "fmt: unmatched line, look also at interestingLine"
```

Comment: Yes, this code is a little primitive. However, it points the way down a useful path. Thanks.